# 2 click events doesn't work in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

kindly i need your support as i tried to add 2 click events as the below but the second section only working and the first section doesn't work till remove the second section

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
                $(function () {
                $("#add_by_serial").click(function () {
                alert("Hello");
                /* var newquantity = $("#serial_newquantity").val();
                var quantityno = $("#serial_quantityno").html();
                var prodcutname = $("#serial_prodcutname").html();
                var serialnumber = $("#serial_serialnumber").html();
                var productid = $("#serial_productid").html();
                var search_by_serial = 1;

                $("#query_result").load("stock/save_edited_quantity.php", { newquantity: newquantity, search_by_serial: search_by_serial, quantityno: quantityno, serialnumber: serialnumber, prodcutname: prodcutname, productid: productid}); */
    })
    })  
    })  
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $(function () {
                $('#add_button').click(function () {

                var product_id = <?php echo $_POST['prod_name']; ?>;
                var quantity = $("#newquantity").val();
                var quantityno = $("#quantityno").html();
                var prodcutname = $("#prodcutname").html();
                var serialnumber = $("#serialnumber").html();
                $("#query_result").load("stock/save_edited_quantity.php", { quantity: quantity, product_id: product_id, quantityno: quantityno, serialnumber: serialnumber, prodcutname: prodcutname});
    })
    })
    })


</script>
```

Comment: side note: why are you having chained document ready calls

Comment: is there an element with id `add_by_serial` also whether the element is added later like using an ajax request or created using script

Comment: <input autocomplete="off"  class="submit" type="button"   id="add_button" style="cursor: pointer;"  value="add"  />
<input autocomplete="off"  class="submit" type="button" id="add_by_serial" style="cursor: pointer;"  value="check" />

Answer (score 1):

add all event in
`$(function(){ });`
or `$( document ).ready(function() { });`

example :

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="add_by_serial">add_by_serial </button>
<button id="add_button">add_button</button>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
                
               $("#add_by_serial").click(function () {
                  alert("بسم الله الرحمن الرحيم1");

                });
  
              $('#add_button').click(function () {
                  alert("بسم الله الرحمن الرحيم2");
  
               });
  

    })


</script>
```

jQuery API Documentation : [jQuery/ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Comment: That's worked for  me, really appreciate your help and support :) :)

Answer (score 0):

Try with this, you should define in the same `ready` event:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#add_by_serial").click(function () {
        alert("Hello");
        /* var newquantity = $("#serial_newquantity").val();
        var quantityno = $("#serial_quantityno").html();
        var prodcutname = $("#serial_prodcutname").html();
        var serialnumber = $("#serial_serialnumber").html();
        var productid = $("#serial_productid").html();
        var search_by_serial = 1;
        $("#query_result").load("stock/save_edited_quantity.php", { newquantity: newquantity, search_by_serial: search_by_serial, quantityno: quantityno, serialnumber: serialnumber, prodcutname: prodcutname, productid: productid}); */
    })  

    $('#add_button').click(function () {
        var product_id = <?php echo $_POST['prod_name']; ?>;
        var quantity = $("#newquantity").val();
        var quantityno = $("#quantityno").html();
        var prodcutname = $("#prodcutname").html();
        var serialnumber = $("#serialnumber").html();
        $("#query_result").load("stock/save_edited_quantity.php", { quantity: quantity, product_id: product_id, quantityno: quantityno, serialnumber: serialnumber, prodcutname: prodcutname});
    })
})  

</script>
```

Comment: still not working as must remove the second click event to make the first one work, could you help me

Answer (score 0):

You have a molformed script. Please read about javascript and jQuery syntax. I soposed that you are trying to set click event to two diferent buttons on load web page, the scrip should be like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

       $("#add_by_serial").click(function () {
       alert("بسم الله الرحمن الرحيم");
       });

       $('#add_button').click(function () {
                var product_id = <?php echo $_POST['prod_name']; ?>;
                var quantity = $("#newquantity").val();
                var quantityno = $("#quantityno").html();
                var prodcutname = $("#prodcutname").html();
                var serialnumber = $("#serialnumber").html();
                $("#query_result").load("stock/save_edited_quantity.php", { quantity: quantity, product_id: product_id, quantityno: quantityno, serialnumber: serialnumber, prodcutname: prodcutname});
       });
    });  
</script>
```

Regards

Comment: thanks Mgamon for your answer and kindly note that i modified my code as per your answer but the first event still doesn't work till remove the second click event, any help

Comment: Please provide your html code for check your elements ;)